# new fragment cannot be loaded by clicking on Drawer item in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I've implemented the following code , but when I run the app and click on an item in Drawer nothing happened. I guess it's a problem related to the Listener but I couldn't grasp how to fix it. or maybe other problem!

once I click on one item the only thing happen is the following two lines in the logcat :

```
01-12 03:14:26.606 1565-1565/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = -1,-1
01-12 03:14:29.601 1565-1565/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
```

here is the code:

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer,dlDrawer;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find our drawer view
        dlDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        dlDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

       nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tx.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, new EditPersonal());
        tx.commit();
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dlDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = EditPersonal.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = Chronogram.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = BloodTest.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_forth_fragment:
                fragmentClass = GlucoseTest.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_fifth_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SendRecord.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_sixth_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ReviewLogin.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_seventh_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SignOut.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = EditPersonal.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent,fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
    // ...
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Make sure this is the method with just `Bundle` as the signature
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

the app screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On your switch case, try something like this:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

case R.id.nav_first_fragment:

     EditPersonal editPersonal= new EditPersonal();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flContent, editPersonal);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
     break;
```

Do this on other cases too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting logs into your code to see where the logic flows to or fails to flow to?

For example inside your switch statement, try seeing if menuItem.getItemId() actually matches your case statements. It'd help to see if your listener is actually the problem or if it's just not matching the cases. Or it could be a problem with your fragment manager.

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html. You should be able to see the logs in logcat. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Basically I have changed the code using the Activity (Navigation Drawer Activity) of Android studio itself. so here is the code :

```
    public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.review_login_listview, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.menu_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_first_fragment) {
            // Handle the camera action
        }
        else {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```